# How to convert regular properties into Automatic properties C#

Tags: c#

```cs
public class MsException : BaseException
{ 
    private readonly string _error;
    private readonly string _message;

    public MsException(int id)
    {
        var code = (Enum)errorId;

        _error = code.ToString();
        _message = code.GetNames();
    }

    public override string StatusCode => _error;
    public override string Message => _message;
}
```

I want to convert those properties into auto properties as C# 6 examples. How they will look like?

In `BaseException` I have two properties again `string StatusCode` and `string Message`.

Any help will be appreciated. I need some example how to do it.

Comment: Please, provide example with the code above, so that we can see working example of how to do it.

Comment: Assuming `BaseException` inherits from Exception, you don't need those properties at all. You should *remove* them and set the existing properties in the constructor. In fact, you should call the appropriate base constructor and pass *a descriptive message*. If you want to store extra data, use the `Data` property, not `Message`

Comment: How does `StatusCode` and `message` looks like in the `BaseException`, code needs to have complete example

Comment: Imagine something goes wrong at 12am, the server is down and you have to read a log file where *all* exception messages are identical. How are you going to fix this? What if your *boss* has to fix this?

Comment: both are public virtual string only with get;

Comment: Am I the only one not understanding this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `StatusCode` and `Message` in base class. You are inheriting that base class and want to set values to base class property then you can simply assign values to that property

```
public class MsException : BaseException
   { 
   public MsException(int id)
      {
         var code = (Enum)errorId;

         this.StatusCode = code.ToString();
         this.Message = code.GetNames();
      }
   }
```

Your `BaseException` class might look like

```
public class BaseException
{
    public string StatusCode {get; set;};
    public string Message {get; set;}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have some terrible mix here since you override properties that are found in `BaseException` which is hardly a good idea, since they already exist.

So you can just use these properties that are already there instead of creating new ones.

Perhaps you can explain why do you need this.

Comment: Why what if the properties are abstract, they need to be overridden

Comment: @MrinalKamboj only if `BaseException` isn't an `Exception`, in which case the name choice is really, really bad.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos agreed, i am guessing due to sheer lack of information

Comment: It is exception , not a bad name.

Comment: @JessikaParker in that case it's not a well designed exception. The Message should explain what's wrong and possibly, ways to fix the problem. Otherwise it's useless. Would you be able to troubleshoot a production error when all log records are identical enum values?

Answer (score 1):

```cs
public class MsException : BaseException
{ 
    public MsException(int id)
    {
        var code = (Enum)errorId;

        StatusCode = code.ToString();
        Message = code.GetNames();
    }
}
```

Something like this may work.